# Using Form Objects with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've moved the creation of a complex series of models out from the model into a form object, but in removing some of the hooks I've managed to break some of my tests.

The problem is that my factory creates the model and depends on the hooks running. The obvious solution here is to change the factory so that it assigns to the form object, but this returns an instance of the form object, necessitating I update every test I've broken. Is there a way to have FactoryGirl create the model using the form object, and then return a *property* of the object it's built (specifically, the property that is the assembled model)?

Here's the current factory - the form object uses the same field names:

```
factory :project do
    status "Project active"
    association :director, factory: :employee
    association :manager, factory: :employee

    category { Settings.project.categories.billable.first }
    estimated_completion_date { Date.current }
    estimated_project_start_date { Date.current }
    name { Faker::Lorem.words.join(' ') }
    likelihood { Settings.project.likelihoods.first }
    project_type { Settings.project.types.first }
    proposal_due_date { Date.current }
    proposal_verdict_date { Date.current }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    research_independence { Settings.project.research_independence.first }

    factory :unsuccessful_proposal do
        status "Proposal unsuccessful"
    end

    factory :proposal_submitted do
        proposal_submitted_date { Date.current }
        status "Proposal submitted"

        after(:build) do |proposal, evaluator|
            proposal.clients << build(:client)
        end
    end
end
```

Edit: I asked this pretty close to Christmas, and it got very little attention. My own research suggests I can use initialize_with in the factory to create my form object, to_create to modify FactoryGirl's saving behaviour, and I might be able to influence FactoryGirl directly with a custom build strategy. If I work out how to do it, I'll return to answer my own question; currently it's not doing associations right but it does appear to be creating a project correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after this got tumbleweeds, I did my own research. The solution: FactoryGirl has a function called `initialize_with`, which can be used for calling `initialize` functions that require arguments. The trick is that `initialize_with` understands `attributes`, which is a hash of all the attributes you've defined in your factory. So for a form, you can call your new(attributes), run whatever else you need to, and then finally return the model or models the form is creating.

For instance:

```
initialize_with do |result|
    form = ProjectForm.new(attributes)
    if form.save!
        result = form.project
    else
        result = form.errors
    end
end
```